# Verifying first digit in string python

Tags: python, string

I am brand new to python and have searched the site on this, but still can't figure it out. It's for a homework assignment, so not looking for the answer, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong and getting a syntax error (I'm stuck on the first rule...)

The assignment:
W​e will assume that the credit card number is a string consisting of 14 characters and is in the format ####-####-####, including the dashes, where ‘#’ represents a digit between 0-9, so that there are 12 digits overall.
1. The first digit must be a 4. 
2. The fourth digit must be one greater than the fifth digit; keep in mind that these are separated by a dash since the format is ####-####-####. 
3. The sum of all digits must be evenly divisible by 4. 
4. If you treat the first two digits as a two-digit number, and the seventh and eighth digits as a two-digit number, their sum must be 100.

Here is my code so far. I've read that you can't compare characters to numbers, but nothing I've tried has worked. Any help/guidance would be appreciated!

```
def verify(number) : 

if input ['0'] == '4'
  return True
if input ['0'] != '4'
  return "violates rule #1"

input = "4000-0000-0000" # change this as you test your function
output = verify(input) # invoke the method using a test input
print(output) # prints the output of the function
```

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect. Please fix that and post the full traceback.

Comment: `input` is a builtin in python. Avoid using that name. Nothing in your function appears to ask for any `input` from the user

Comment: `if input[0]`, not `input ['0']`

Comment: To get the first character of a string, use `text[0]`, not `text['0']`.

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine, but there are a couple of issues

```
def verify(number) : 

   if input [0] == '4':
     return True
   if input [0] != '4':
     return "violates rule #1"

input = "4000-0000-0000" # change this as you test your function
output = verify(input) # invoke the method using a test input
print(output) # prints the output of the function
```

first of all, indentation matters in python, everything that belongs in your function definition should be indented.

second, if statements should be followed by `:`. that is all

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect:

```
def verify(number): 
# incorrect indent here
if input ['0'] == '4' # missing : and undeclared input variable, index should be int
   return True
if input ['0'] != '4'   # missing : and undeclared input variable, index should be int
  return "violates rule #1"
```

Fixed code:

```
def verify(number):
    if number[0] != '4'
        return "violates rule #1"
    # other checks here
    return True
```

Also I recommend to return `False` from this function instead of error string. If you want to return string with error, consider using tuple like `(is_successful, error)` or custom object.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [string indexing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings):

> Strings can be indexed (subscripted), with the first character having
>   index 0. There is no separate character type; a character is simply a
>   string of size one:

```
>>> word = 'Python'
>>> word[0]  # character in position 0 'P'
>>> word[5]  # character in position 5 'n'
```

Then read about [if-statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements) - your code is missing the `:`, and the second `if` can be replaced by an `else` clause.

You may also want to check the argument of the function, not the global variable `input` (this is a bad name, since it shadows the [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) built-in)

Suggested fix:

```
def verify(number) : 
    if number[0] == '4':
        return True
    else:
        return "violates rule #1"

testinput = "4000-0000-0000" # change this as you test your function
output = verify(testinput) # invoke the method using a test input
print(output) # prints the output of the function
```